# Hash function in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hash, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to add a column to a dataframe, which will contain **hash of another column**.

I've found this piece of documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#hash
And tried this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = spark.read.parquet(...)
val withHashedColumn = df.withColumn("hashed", hash($"my_column"))
```

But what is the hash function used by that `hash()`? Is that `murmur`, `sha`, `md5`, something else?

The value I get in this column is integer, thus range of values here is probably `[-2^(31) ... +2^(31-1)]`.
Can I get a long value here? Can I get a string hash instead?
How can I specify a concrete hashing algorithm for that?
Can I use a custom hash function?

Comment: One of the wonders of _open source_ is that you can look at the [**source**](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L2124) as you can see they use `Murmur3`. There is also another function [`sha2`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@sha2(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,numBits:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column).

Answer (score 20):

It is Murmur based on the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d2bdd6595ec3495672c60e225948c99bfaeff04a/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L2464):

```
  /**
   * Calculates the hash code of given columns, and returns the result as an int column.
   *
   * @group misc_funcs
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
  @scala.annotation.varargs
  def hash(cols: Column*): Column = withExpr {
    new Murmur3Hash(cols.map(_.expr))
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want a Long hash, in spark 3 there is the `xxhash64` function: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/api/sql/index.html#xxhash64.

You may want only positive numbers. In this case you may use `hash` and sum `Int.MaxValue` as

```
df.withColumn("hashID", hash($"value").cast(LongType)+Int.MaxValue).show()
```

Comment: Hi if I only want positive numbers, how can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: @Galuoises  , can you people provide some more resources where these can be used in spark context how to use in data skewness and other area.

Comment: @shasu, sorry but what you are asking is not related to the question of the page. Please open a new stackoverflow question